# ServiceStack and Fody Costura

Tags: servicestack, fody-costura

I'm pretty new to ServiceStack, so apologies in advance if the nomenclature is not 100%.

I create a test self-hosted application and the ServiceStack Service was in the same assembly as the mainline code. All good.

I then moved the code to production use, and service now lives in a separate assembly to the main code. Initially, I have a test harness that I use to make sure everything works fine, and then a windows service that references that same assembly. Fairly sure this would be normal usage.

The test harness works fine, however for production use, I have used Fody Costura to embed the assemblies into a single executable (makes it easier to copy from dev machine to production machine was my thinking).

When using Fody Costura to embed the assembly into the executable, ServiceStack returns an error during the Init() (invalid path). I have tested this and it seems that the ServiceStack Service class needs to be in a physical assembly file that can be loaded, and not a resource.

Is there are known work around for this, or do I need to retain the code in its own assembly for ServiceStack to work?

Thanks in advance.
Craig

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Fody Costura impact, but the [ServiceStack.Gap](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Gap) project shows how you can ILMerge ServiceStack into a single cross-platform .exe.